# Chrome and IE jerkiness on key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Page smoothly scrolls well in Firefox but give a slight jerk in chrome and IE on pressing arrow key

http://jsfiddle.net/cZuym/39/

```
function wheel(event) {
if (event.wheelDelta) delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;
else if (event.detail) delta = -event.detail / 3;

handle();
if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
event.returnValue = false;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Actually `DOMMouseScroll` event only works with mozilla (Gecko)!!

Or in other words mozilla only support this event!!

You have to try `mousewheel` event not tested but it works in ie & chrome but not in mozilla!!

So you can use `mousewheel` for ie & chrome & `DOMMouseScroll` for mozilla!!